# Change the height from a RelativeLayout inside costumeadapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Hey guys I'm newbie at Android development, and I would like to build a sub item for each listview item.

Just like this:

> > ListView 1
>
> sub item 1
>
> > ListView 1
>
> sub item 1

I though that it would be esier to create a new relative layout for each listview item, so my XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrap_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_col"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/overlay_bg" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="9dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/current_event"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:letterSpacing="1.2"
                android:shadowColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:shadowDx="-2"
                android:shadowDy="2"
                android:shadowRadius="0.01"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/persons" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_day"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_col"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each item is divided by two columns, the second column should be hidden column, thats why I changed the layout height to 200dp.

And to show the full layout, I'm doing that:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
            final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            final RelativeLayout lebg = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.wrap_layout);


            lebg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View b) {

                    lebg.getLayoutParams().height = 400;
                }
            });
            return v; 
        }
```

I just need to change the height from 200 to 400 to show the full Listview item.

**The issue:**

Is not working that well because when I click at the listview it only changes the height when I scroll...

Is there any better way to do what I am trying?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should look into ExpandableListView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change `LayoutParams` you have to call `requestLayout` to see changes:

```
lebg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View b) {
        lebg.getLayoutParams().height = 400;
        requestLayout();
    }
});
```